# PHP/HTML linking Step 2 to call the filename uploaded in Step 1

Tags: php, redirect, filenames

This is what I have done.  I've modified the front-end uploaded for the SermonSpeaker module that our church is using to where I can connect our S3 Amazon cloud to store our sermon mp3s. The original front end form is 2 parts.  The first part is uploading the mp3 audio which originally linked to the second part of the form where you can add the sermon title, scripture, etc...  It would display the name of the file on the 2nd part of the form and once completed, would officially post the sermon, and have the path correctly routed in the sermon audio link.  I used the tutorial for the S3 Amazon post that has worked like a charm, and I have been able to successfully redirect part 1 of the form to part 2, but the filename shows up as " .$filename', and the direct link shows up on the Joomla backend hows up as "/http://cpcpca-sermons.s3.amazonaws.com//'.$filename"

I also wanted it to reject any file types that are non-mp3s.  The conditions feature of the base64 policy that I used don't seem to work as I've uploaded pdf files as a test, and they've gone through instead of being denied.  I'm still a noob on most of this stuff, but I feel so close to a breakthrough.  Here's a copy of the files that I've been working on.

This is the section that I used to call the redirect to step 2:

```
 <?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
?>
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width ="50"></td>
        <td><h1><?php echo JText::_('COM_SERMONSPEAKER_FU_NEWSERMON'); ?></h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width ="50"></td>
        <td><b><?php echo JText::_('COM_SERMONSPEAKER_FU_STEP'); ?> 1 : </b><?php echo JText::_('COM_SERMONSPEAKER_FU_STEP1'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan ="4">&#160;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width ="50"></td>
        <td align='left'>

<form action="http://s3.amazonaws.com/cpcpca-sermons" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}" />
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
<input type="hidden" name="content-type" value="audio/mp3" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.cpcpca.org/index.php?option=com_sermonspeaker&view=fu_step_2&filename='.$filename" />
<input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="REMOVED" />
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="REMOVED"/>
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="REMOVED" />

      <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

      File to upload: 
      <input name="file" type="file"> 
      <br> 
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Sermon"> 
     Please upload mp3's only.
    </form> 
            <br/>&nbsp;<br/>
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width ="50"></td>
        <td><?php echo SermonspeakerHelperSermonspeaker::fu_logoffbtn(); ?></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose the php variables in php tags:  for them to be treated as php code, otherwise it is considered html. Also in the url you have to echo the variable `http://www.cpcpca.org/index.php?option=com_sermonspeaker&view=fu_step_2&filename=<?php echo $filename ?>`

Comment: I'm getting errors like, "Invalid Policy: Invalid JSON."  Where do I put my end quote mark on the line.  I have to mirror it the same way in the policy.  This is what I added: '<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="httx://www.cpcpca.org/index.php?option=com_sermonspeaker&view=fu_step_2&filename="<?php echo $filename ?> /></php>'  I deliberately used httx instead of http due to limited formatting issue

Comment: I would do something like this (no need for </php> tag): '<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="httx://www.cpcpca.org/index.php?option=com_sermonspeaker&view=fu_step_2&f‌​ilename="<?php echo $filename ?>"/>'

Comment: Though it works for the php file, I'm having problems with using it in the S3 Amazon policy.  Adding the redirect line:  {"redirect": "httx://www.cpcpca.org/index.php?option=com_sermonspeaker&view=fu_step_2&f‌​‌​ilename="<?php echo $filename ?>"}, yields an error: Invalid Policy: Invalid JSON.